# Firebase hosting rewrites to functions not working as expected

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am building a static website with HTML, CSS & JS and hosted on firebase hosting and connected a custom domain. The only serverside function I need is to send mail from the contact form. For this, I am trying to use Firebase cloud function. I have initialized functions on the same project and trying to use firebase hosting rewrites to rewrite the request to `mydomain.com/contact` to the contact function. But when I try to access the `mydomain.com/contact` in the browser it shows the below 403 Forbidden error message.

```
Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /contact/contact from this server.
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "/contact",
      "function": "contact"
    }],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }
}
```

The cloud function (not implemented the actual logic)

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

exports.contact = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("<h1>Contact<h1>");
});
```

*I am using Firebase spark plan.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
"rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "**",
      "function": "myApp"
    }
  ]
```

And in the express function,

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import express from 'express';
const app = express();

app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
  res.send("<h1>Contact<h1>");
};

export const myApp = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Are you using express? can you share the full function code?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue this week. I had a rewrite from /user to a function called user and I was getting the response `Your client does not have permission to get URL /user/user from this server.`

I just deleted the functions from the firebase console then deployed them again and now they work. There must be some occasional bug with deploying functions like this and/or using hosting rewrites where the rewrite path gets appended to the function url path on the server.